# VBA - How do I compare text in Excel cells to see if same words are found, exclusing punctuation?

Tags: excel, vba

I have numerous rows of Excel cells which contain a string of words, there are commas and hyphens in some, but general text with just spaced in others. I want to compare each cell with another cell to check if any of the words match/are duplicates.

I've found some VBA codes - but it only helps with some cells and not others and I'm not sure why. How do I remove punctuation so the results come up showing the duplicated values (if there are no values - a statement of No Match)

The code I've been using:

```
Function DupeWord(str1 As String, str2 As String) As String
  Dim vArr1
  Dim vArr2
  Dim vTest
  Dim lngCnt As Long

  vArr1 = Split(Replace(str1, " ", vbNullString), ",")
  vArr2 = Split(Replace(str2, " ", vbNullString), ",")
  On Error GoTo strExit

  For lngCnt = LBound(vArr1) To UBound(vArr1)
    vTest = Application.Match(vArr1(lngCnt), vArr2, 0)
    If Not IsError(vTest) Then DupeWord = DupeWord & vArr1(lngCnt) & ", "
  Next lngCnt

  If Len(DupeWord) > 0 Then
    DupeWord = Left$(DupeWord, Len(DupeWord) - 2)
  Else
strExit:
    DupeWord = "No Matches!"
  End If
End Function
```

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself.

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: Rachel, I would start by listing all separators ie, `.`, `,`,` `,`;`, `:`, `/` etc then split the string using those separators to get single words.

Comment: I would remove the `On Error` statement and see if a specific formatting of an entry is causing an early exit.  Then we can target that error and solve it.

Comment: It's a shame I can't add pictures yet to show you what it's doing but I've removed the "On Error" that doesn't make any difference at all.

Comment: It would help to update your question with a specific example of two strings which are giving the "wrong" result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest making use of two very powerful classes: RegExp and Dictionary.  You can add them to your VBA project by clicking Tools ---> References... and checking the boxes next to "Microsoft VBcript Regular Expressions 5.5" and "Microsoft Scripting Runtime".

Replace your code with the following:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function DupeWord(str1 As String, str2 As String) As String
    Dim dictStr1Words As New Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim colDupeWords As New Collection

    'Set up the Regular Expression
    Dim oRegExp As New RegExp
    Dim oMatches As MatchCollection
    Dim oMatch As Match
    With oRegExp
      .Global = True
      .Multiline = True
      .Pattern = "([\w']+)"   'Matches any word character including underscore. Equivalent to '[A-Za-z0-9_']'
      Set oMatches = .Execute(str1)
    End With

    'Add each word in Str1 into a Scripting.Dictionary
    For Each oMatch In oMatches
        If Not dictStr1Words.Exists(oMatch.Value) Then
            dictStr1Words.Add oMatch.Value, 0
        End If
    Next

    Set oMatches = oRegExp.Execute(str2)

    'Check to see if any of the words found in Str2 was in Str1 using the Scripting.Dictionary function Exists
    For Each oMatch In oMatches
        If dictStr1Words.Exists(oMatch.Value) Then
            colDupeWords.Add oMatch.Value  'Add any dups to a collection
        End If
    Next

    'If there are any dup words in the collection, join them up as a comma separated list, otherwise return "No Matches!"
    If colDupeWords.Count > 0 Then
        DupeWord = JoinStringCollection(colDupeWords, ", ")
    Else
        DupeWord = "No Matches!"
    End If

End Function

Public Function JoinStringCollection(colStrings As Collection, strDelimiter As String) As String
'This function joins a collection with a delimiter so that there is no need to lop off a trailing or leading delimiter
    Dim strOut As String
    Dim i As Long

    If colStrings.Count > 0 Then
        strOut = colStrings.Item(1)
    End If

    If colStrings.Count > 1 Then
        For i = 2 To colStrings.Count
            strOut = strOut & strDelimiter & colStrings.Item(i)
        Next
    End If

    JoinStringCollection = strOut
End Function
```

The Regular Expression splits the strings into words based not on the space or commas that may separate them, but upon what constitutes a valid word.  By the "pattern" I used, a word can only be constructed from uppercase letters A-Z, lowercase letters a-z, numbers 0-9 (could be a few in a row), the underscore _, and the apostrophe ' in case there are contractions.  Everything else is ignored as punctuation or delimiters.  You can change this to suit your needs.  You can read more about Regular Expressions [here, a general reference on what Regular Expressions are and can do](http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html), and [here, a more specific list of rules for the VBScript RegExp class](http://www.kingsley-hughes.com/tech/script/vbscript/regular_expressions_vbscript.php).

Comment: Blackhawk - thank you so much! The comments you put in the script were so helpful. :-) very much appreciated!